# XAML: The property "Content" can only be set once - though already only set once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set up a material design in a C# XMAL WPF application.
I added ["Material Design In XAML"](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/home) to my project, after which I got the following error: `The property 'Content' can only be set once` where would be the problem in my mark up? I've provided the file which gives the error below:

```
<Window x:Class="e621_fetch.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:e621_fetch"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
    TextElement.FontSize="13"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}">
<Grid>
    <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16"> //error on this line
              
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}">My First Material Design App</TextBlock> //error on this line
            
    </materialDesign:Card> //error on this line
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

already fixed it, it was because of the blank lines in between the tags...

Comment: no idea why the downvote, it fixed the issue and seems to be clear enough

Comment: the downvotes could have with the time 2 minutes after you postet the question you gave an answer to your own question. Looks like you did not even try to fix it yourself before you posted it here on stackoverflow.

Comment: The whole purpose of SOF is to have questions and answers. Thanks @Grey to have gone through the trouble to post your Q and A here.